# how to use Or operator in jquery

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to user or operator in jquery but looks like the code renders without error but it's not implemented. only icjpg.gif are rendered on the page.

```
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("img[src$='icjpg.gif']").each(SetImage) || $("img[src$='icpng.gif']").each(SetImage);

});
function SetImage()
{
    $(this).attr('height','100');
    $(this).attr('src','/it/Site/DocLib/'+$(this).attr('title')); 
}
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to accomplish with `or`. The conditional code shown doesn't make sense

Comment: what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: if icjpg.gif or icpng.gif is present then it will replace it actual big picture.

Comment: You don't need the OR at all if you just want to set the attributes all those matching images. Just call the function on each line.

Comment: If I take out everything after the pipe on line 3 then it only shows picture that had a thumbnail icon of icjpg.gif

Comment: SharePoint has a built in column "Type" and it put relevant icon for the item. for example, jpg gets icjpg.gif, word get doc.gif, etc.

Comment: I can repeat entire code just for icpng.gif and it works. but why repeat if I can use or operator

Comment: You can select both types at the same time. See @charlietfl answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is use both selectors if you want to affect both

```
$("img[src$='icjpg.gif'], img[src$='icpng.gif']").each(SetImage);
```

The reason that your second condition is never met is that a jQuery object will always be truthy so the `or` never runs

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using an OR-operator here?
An OR statement is used to see if at least one of two statements is TRUE.
You use it for instance in an IF-statement where you want to execute a piece of code ***if*** one or the other is TRUE.

What you try to achieve here as far as I can tell, is set the attributes of all icjpg.gif images, and also set the attributes of all icpng.gif images.

Try this:

```
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("img[src$='icjpg.gif']").each(SetImage);
$("img[src$='icpng.gif']").each(SetImage);

});
function SetImage()
{
    $(this).attr('height','100');
    $(this).attr('src','/it/Site/DocLib/'+$(this).attr('title')); 
}
</SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't make heads or tails of your code... Are you trying to do a conditional statement with or? like:

```
if(a || b){}else{}
```

The Or conditional will check the left side first, if it is true then it won't check the right side. Does this helps?